# Merging / connecting geometrical entities

Tags: algorithm

I have container of geometrical entities. Let's assume there is circle, ellipse, line, arc.
For each entity i can get entity endpoint and entity startpoint.

Entities can be connected so endpoints of entity can be also endpoint of another entity.

So we have entity: startpoint, endpoint, id

I want to assign for each connected entity same id.

If three entities have one common point as connected entities should be treated longer path.

What is the most efficient way to do so? My only idea so far is to iterate over whole container and check in loops each entity with others.

I hope that problem is well defined and tags are ok. If not, please comment or edit. I will try to provide further details.

Comment: So much here is under specified. Unless you have huge numbers of entities, you can just iterate over them and check which ones have matching endpoints, with two loops. Or iterate over entities once, putting them in a hash table by endpoint hashes, then check for common endpoints out of the hash bins.

Comment: Two loops you mean Loop{Loop} so second loop nested in first?

Comment: Yes. Let me make a proper answer with pseudo code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @RafaelBaptista's suggestion of an endpoint hash, an efficient general solution requires a [disjoint-set datastructure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure), which solves the problem of assigning a single ID for connected groups of entities.

As mentioned in the link, an efficient disjoint-set algorithm is "practically linear" -- formally, it might be a bit slower than linear, but for practical problem sizes, the difference is within a factor of 5.

Comment: Thanks for nice reference. Very nice there is boost implementation. Now I'm looking for some way to cope the case 3 entities meet in one point and I want in that case to take longer path.

Comment: Maybe I should consider some longest path search in connected components graph?

Comment: If you actually want the longest path, then yes: treat each component as an arc, each endpoint as a node, and use the appropriate graph algorithm.  Note that "longest path" is NP-complete, but for small graphs you should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

For small numbers of entities:

```
for ( u32 i = 0; i < numEntities; i++ )
{
   for ( u32 j = i+1; j < numEntities; j++ )
   {
       if ( hasCommonEndpoint( entity[i], entity[j] ))
          setSameId( entity[i], entity[j] ) 
   }
}
```

This scales as O(n^2), so it will blow up if you have a large numbers of entities. It also assumes that entities that match on endpoint will not match on any other endpoint. If that happened then you would need to allow entities to have more than one id.

Note that the inner loop starts for j > i, so you don't compare the same entity more than once. This will cut the time in half.

If you have a large number number of entities you will want to do something like:

```
HashTable<endpointHash, entity> dict; 
for ( u32 i = 0; i < numEntities; i++ )
{
   dict.insert( entity[i].endpointHash(), entity[i] );
}
```

Where HashTable hosts a list of all entities that have endpoints with the same endpoint hash. Then for each list iterate over the elements of the list matching endpoints in the same way as the first loop. This will scale much better roughly O(n) + O(m^2), where N is large and M is small. Actual performance will depend on the quality of the hash function, and the number of hash bins.

Comment: Thanks for solution in pseudocode. Of course it's obvious. But both solution don't cope case that three endpoints are the same. As I said in this case same id should be assigned for entities which create the longest chain. So to connect should be choosen the entity to which can be connected larger number of entities.

Comment: No. It will work if there are multiple entities with the same endpoints. What won't work is if you have an entity A with one enpoint in common with B, and another in common with C, but C and B don't have one in common.

Comment: But I think it will work not the way I want. If 3 entities have one common point connected should be entity which will allow to connect more entities (creating longest path).